# Transform foreach to Java 8 filter stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code

```
Map<String, List<String>> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", Arrays.asList("a1"));
map.put("b", Arrays.asList("a2"));

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("c");

for (String names : list) {
    if (!map.containsKey(names)) {
          result.add(names);
    }
}
```

And I tried to migrate it to Java 8. What am I doing wrong?

```
list.stream()
    .filter(c -> !map.containsKey(Name))
    .forEach(c -> result.add(c));
```

But my condition is not evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
list.stream().filter(c-> !map.containsKey(c)).forEach(result::add);
```

A better way is:

```
List<String> result = list.stream().filter(c -> !map.constainsKey(c)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The New list should contain only the New value. If you check the foreach loop with if clause, in result is stored only what is not in the map

Comment: Yes. Your code does not add in the result list "c" value from the iterated list if it is not in the Map. I did manage to achieve what I want with clasic for code written above. The problem in lambda, My condition is somehow ignored or I am not collecting it right.

Comment: You are right. Your code is corect. Due my run I didn t get the corect result. Sorry and thanks

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it should be:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(c-> !map.containsKey(c))
    .forEach(c->result.add(c));
```

Second of all, it's better to use `collect` as the terminal `Stream` operation when you want to produce a `List`:

```
List<String> result = 
    list.stream()
        .filter(c-> !map.containsKey(c))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list.stream()
    .filter(c -> !map.containsKey(c))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 2):

- `Name` is not defined anywhere in the scope. The name of the lambda parameter is `c`. You should use it.
- `collect(Collectors.toList())` should be used to remove the explicit declaration and make it more expressive.

---

```
List<String> result = 
        list.stream()
            .filter(c -> !map.containsKey(c))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```